# OpenWebBeans gives error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using with Tomcat 10

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, classnotfoundexception, openwebbeans, tomcat10

I am trying to use OpenWebBeans with Tomcat 10. I have followed the steps given in this [link](https://balusc.omnifaces.org/2013/10/how-to-install-cdi-in-tomcat.html).

When I use Weld, it works fine. But when I use OpenWebBeans, I get the following error.

```
SEVERE: Error configuring application listener of class [org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContextListener ...
```

My pom file is as follows

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>minimal</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>
        UTF-8
    </project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        UTF-8
    </project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.annotation</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.annotation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.faces</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>openwebbeans-jsf</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
version="4.0">
<display-name>minimal</display-name>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>jakarta.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>facesServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<listener>
<listener-class>
org.apache.webbeans.servlet.WebBeansConfigurationListener
</listener-class>
</listener>
```

This is my context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE XML>
<Context>
<Resource name="BeanManager" 
    auth="Container"
    type="jakarta.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager"
    factory="org.apache.webbeans.container.ManagerObjectFactory" />
</Context>
```

I am required to migrate to the jakarta namespace using OpenWebBeans. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *I am required to migrate to the jakarta namespace using OpenWebBeans.*

They do have a Jakartified version since [2.0.15](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/openwebbeans/openwebbeans-jsf/2.0.15/). Simply add `<classifier>jakarta</classifier>` to the dependency.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>openwebbeans-jsf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```

It has currently however only one problem: its four transitive dependencies `web`, `el22`, `impl` and `spi` are incorrectly **not** the Jakartified variants. So you need to explicitly exclude them and explicitly include the Jakartified variants. So you're forced to end up with this monster graph:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>openwebbeans-jsf</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-web</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-el22</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>openwebbeans-web</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-el22</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>openwebbeans-el22</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>openwebbeans-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openwebbeans</groupId>
    <artifactId>openwebbeans-spi</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.21</version>
    <classifier>jakarta</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering if this is fixed, this seems to be the issue to track: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OWB-1368